# Python: Convert tuple to comma separated String

Tags: python, mysql, string, tuples, python-2.x

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","password","database")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM some_table")
u_data = cursor.fetchall()

>>> print u_data
((1320088L,),)
```

What I found on internet got me till here:

```
string = ((1320088L,),)
string = ','.join(map(str, string))
>>> print string
(1320088L,)
```

what I expect output to look like:

```
 #Single element expected result
 1320088L  
 #comma separated list if more than 2 elements, below is an example
 1320088L,1320089L
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `itertools.chain_fromiterable()` to flatten your nested tuples first, then `map()` to string and `join()`. Note that `str()` removes the `L` suffix because the data is no longer of type `long`.

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> s = ((1320088L,),)
>>> ','.join(map(str,chain.from_iterable(s)))
'1320088'

>>> s = ((1320088L,1232121L),(1320088L,),)
>>> ','.join(map(str,chain.from_iterable(s)))
'1320088,1232121,1320088'
```

Note, `string` is not a good variable name because it is the same as the [`string`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) module.

Answer (score 6):

I think the `string` is a `tuple` of `tuple` containing long values.

```
>>> string = ((1320088L,),)
>>> ','.join(str(y) for x in string for y in x if len(x) > 0)
'1320088'
>>>
```

e.g. with more than one value

```
>>> string = ((1320088L,1232121L),(1320088L,),)
>>> ','.join(str(y) for x in string for y in x if len(x) > 0)
'1320088,1232121,1320088'
>>>
```

Comment: This answer generalizes well for tuples with length > 1.

Comment: not sure if @Chris_Rands answer is a better one. This answer and his answer both work for me!

Comment: @JackSparrow these days itertools is the recommended way to flatten lists or tuples http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python

Answer (score -1):

```
string = ((1320088L,),)
print(','.join(map(str, list(sum(string, ())))))
string = ((1320088L, 1232121L), (1320088L,),)
print(','.join(map(str, list(sum(string, ())))))
```

Output:

```
1320088
1320088,1232121,1320088
```