# Write MySQL result to a CSV file in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python, mysql, csv, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I need to write a result set from MySQL ina csv format inside a bucket in Google Cloud Storage.

Following the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/blobstore/#Python_Using_the_Blobstore_API_with_Google_Cloud_Storage), I created the following example code:

```
import cloudstorage
from google.appengine.api import app_identity
import db # My own Mysql wrapper

dump = db.get_table_dump(schema) # Here I made a simples SQL SELECT and fetchall()
bucket_name = app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name()
file_name = "/" + bucket_name + "/finalfiles/" + schema + "/" +"myfile.csv"
with cloudstorage.open(file_name, "w") as gcsFile:
    gcsFile.write(dump)
```

It did not work 'cause `write` expects a string parameter and `dump` is tuple of tuples result from `fetchall()`.

I can't use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952366/dump-csv-from-sqlalchemy) (or similar) since I can't write files in GAE enviroment and I also can't create a CSV string from tuple like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40993966/python-convert-tuple-to-comma-separated-string), due to the size o my result set (Actually, I tried it and it takes too long and it timed out before finish).

So, my question is, which is the best way to get a result set from MySQL and save it as CSV in a Google Cloud Storage Bucket?

Comment: Can you write to in memory files?

Comment: Sorry @JohannesReichard, but I did't understand your question. I'm kind of new in GAE. Are memory files something that I can write in?

Comment: I never used GAE but python not only supports to write to a file on a hard drive but also to a file like object which lives in memory: docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#in-memory

Comment: Thank for the link @JohannesReichard. I'll see if it works, but looks promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just went through the same problem with PHP. I ended up using the cloud sql api (https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/v1beta4/) with the following workflow:

1. Create an export bucket (i.e. test-exports)
2. Give the SQL Instance Read/Write permissions to the bucket created in step 1
3. Within the application, make a call to instance export (https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/v1beta4/instances/export). This endpoint accepts the SQL to run, as well as a path to an output bucket. (created in step (1))
4. Step (3) will return back an operation with a 'name' property. You can use this 'name' and poll the operations/get endpoint (https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/v1beta4/operations/get) until the status is returned as DONE

We have a job which performs these steps nightly (as well as an import using the /import command) on 6 tables and have yet to see any issues. The only thing to keep in mind is that only one operation can run on a single database instance at a time. To combat this, you should the top item from the the operations list endpoint (https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/v1beta4/operations/list) to confirm the database is ready before issuing any commands.