# Convert key value tuple to a comma string

Tags: python

I have a python tuple with the following format:

```
({'day': '03/06', 'stock': 10}, {'day': '04/06', 'stock': 12}, {'day': '05/06', 'stock': 5})
```

I would like to get a comma separated string with each key pair:

```
days = '03/06, 04/06, 05/06'
stocks = '10, 12, 5'
```

I'm using a loop with range and len to extract the values, but I think it's not optimal.

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17426386/how-to-transform-a-tuple-to-a-string-of-values-without-comma-and-parentheses) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40993966/python-convert-tuple-to-comma-separated-string) suggestion but I don't get the results I'm looking for.
Is there a better way to get these values without a loop?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean without a loop? What is it you are actually trying to avoid?

Answer (score 2):

Using a list comprehension:

```py
inp = ({'day': '03/06', 'stock': 10}, {'day': '04/06', 'stock': 12}, {'day': '05/06', 'stock': 5})
days = ', '.join([x['day'] for x in inp])
stocks = ', '.join([str(x['stock']) for x in inp])
print(days)    # 03/06, 04/06, 05/06
print(stocks)  # 10, 12, 5
```

Answer (score 2):

You can extract values of the desired keys from the input sequence of dicts by mapping the sequence to `operator.itemgetter`, and then convert the sequence of day-stock pairs into two sequences of values for days and stocks using `zip`.

Assuming that your input sequence is stored in `data`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

days, stocks = zip(*map(itemgetter('day', 'stock'), data))
```

Comment: Is there a way to output a result like this using your method: "03/06", "04/06", "05/06"? Thanks